# Declaring a query string as a variable - how do I?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to create a partial SQL query as a variable and re-use this query string across multiple databases as per below. I have about 30 databases and would ideally like to swop in and out the query string:

```
declare @SQLQuery nvarchar(4000) = 'StockCode from InvMaster'

USE EncoreCompanyO
select 'USA-O' as Country,  @SQLQuery

USE EncoreCompanyC
select 'Europe(Euro)-C'as Country,  @SQLQuery
```

The above simply outputs the string from the variable - anyone know how to easily do this , or something along the lines.

Comment: You need to make the whole statement dynamic.

Comment: Have you looked at `sp_executesql`

Comment: You don't, the solution would be more complicated than just typing it out.

Answer (score 0):

If I uderstand your requirement this looks like a possible use-case for a *system procedure*.

From your example code, you appear to have a scenario where you have the same table-object and defined schema existing across multiple databases where you wish perform a common query and also inject a bespoke column value.

For this you could use a *system* procedure in the *master* database.

First define your procedure:

```
use master;
go

create procedure sp_test 
@param varchar(50)
as
set nocount, xact_abort on;

select @param as MyColumn, OtherColumn
from dbo.myTableThatExistsInMultipledatabases;

go
```

Then mark it as a system object:

```
exec sys.sp_MS_marksystemobject 'sp_test'
```

Then use it from any database context:

```
Use Db1
go
exec sp_test 'some value';

Use Db2
go
exec sp_test 'another value';
```

Comment: i doubt that that is here the case @SQLQuery  can be everything from climun name till FROM clause  and so on

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below in Sql Server:

```
declare @SQLQuery nvarchar(4000) = 'StockCode from InvMaster',
@Sql Nvarchar(max)

USE EncoreCompanyO
 Set @Sql='Select ''USA-O'' Country,'+@SQLQuery
 EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @Sql

USE EncoreCompanyC
Set @Sql='Select ''Europe(Euro)-C'' Country,'+@SQLQuery
 EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @Sql
```